# track events such as, who checked-in, who uploaded pictures on a certain venue on Foursquare using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, foursquare

Can you track events such as, who checked-in, who uploaded pictures on a certain venue on Foursquare? Im not only talking about numbers but also the user involved on the event. Is this possible? And by the way, im doing this on AS3, will there be some complications regarding this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless a user authenticates your app, you cannot access their check-in information. You can, however, retrieve photos for a venue via the [venues/VENUE_ID/photos](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos) endpoint